# How can i read the text inside the node of an example in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

This is the XML that i want to read.

```
<Server ServerName="SP-SWD-T01">
    Some nodes are there 
</Server>
```

I want to read the ServerName inside the server how can i read it.Please help.

This is the code

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            readerSettings.IgnoreComments = false;
            XmlReader xmlRdr = XmlReader.Create(strFilePath, readerSettings);
            // Parse the file
            while (xmlRdr.Read())
            {
                switch (xmlRdr.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        // You may need to capture the last element to provide a context
                        // for any comments you come across... so copy xmlRdr.Name, etc.
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                        MessageBox.Show(xmlRdr.Name);
                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        //Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        //Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        //Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: xml doesen't have `*` in the tag

Comment: I would use XMLReader.  Why does your XML contain two '**' before the element name and two '**' after the element value?

Comment: actually i have added the stars to show what i want to read i want to read the servername is there a way to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String xml = @"<Server ServerName=""SP-SWD-T01"">Some nodes are there</Server>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
String servername = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Server").Attributes["ServerName"].Value;
```